# Building Mini-OS

Tags: interrupt, bios

I'm Building a Mini-OS, but I don't want to use BIOS interrupt for displaying Graphics. Ex int 10, etc. So, is there any other way, I can use to display graphics instead of the BIOS interrupts. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you use a low screen resolution (resolutions under 64kB; for example  320x200 with 256 colors), you can access the screen on segment 0a000h for graphics modes (offset of the upper left corner is 0) and on segment 0b800h or 0b000h for text modes (if the current screenpage is 0, the offset of the upper left corner is 0). Using assembly, it will work. To set the video mode store the video mode number you want to use at segment 0040h on offset 0049h.